# Using sed with ^A

Tags: bash, shell, sed, tr

I have a file with contents like this:

```
name^Agroup^Ahost
name^Agroup^Ahost    
name^Agroup^Ahost
```

and I need it to be like this:

```
name group host
name group host
name group host
```

Trying the following, but none working:

```
sed -i 's/\^A/ /g' thefile.file
sed -i 's/^A/ /g' thefile.file
```

Help?

Comment: Your first attempt looks fine to me. I suspect that you don't actually have those characters `^A` in the file but they're being rendered like that due to an encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr` instead:

```
tr '\001' ' ' < inputfile
```

In sed, ^ doesn't mean Ctrl, but beginning-of-line.

Comment: Thanks Roland - Typing ctrl+a to produce the ^A sequence works surprisingly :-D